# Easiest way to make a resistor

Tags: resistors, resistance, multimeter

What do I need to make a resistor of about 10 kΩ? After I make it, how do I measure the resistance with this device:

[image: Multimeter]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Most of us would series connect two 5k resistors. What exactly are you trying to do, what materials do you have available and how much of a hurry are you in that you wouldn't buy one for €0.02? Did you read the manual for the meter?

Comment: The AI thinks I need to be more specific with the thread. I don't know what it means, it is a simple question...

Comment: I don't need to use the resistor for anything, I just want to know if it is possible and how to make a resistor from ordinary objects...

Comment: @Bogdan Define "ordinary objects." If you mean it in the sense that a Venezuelan Yanomami tribesman might consider ordinary, then that's one thing. If you mean it in the sense that an electronics engineer might consider ordinary, that's another. I think we need a little help about what's ordinary to you. Of course, you apparently do have a digital voltmeter. So perhaps I should use that as guidance. But I think the question still remains, anyway.

Comment: Buy one? Use resistive wire and wind enough turns?

Answer (score 3):

Stick two wires in a glass of water with an insulator separating them (for example, drill holes in a couple pieces of plastic to hold them a fixed distance apart). Keep the immersion distance stable as well.

Add table salt until the resistance drops to 10K.

This kind of resistor was once used to dim stage lights in theatres. It won't be a very good resistor but it's simple. In particular it will drop in resistance with an increase in water temperature, as well as electrolytic effects and the water evaporating or boiling.

Resistors are the cheapest and most available component, easily procured, hardly worth salvaging, but easy to salvage and frequently even marked as to value and perhaps tolerance, so there's not much incentive to make something that is almost guaranteed to be inferior unless  you have a garage that looks like [Ben's garage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLkVFjRyoDU) replete with tube furnaces, high vacuum systems and sputtering apparatus.

Comment: Re, "once used to dim stage lights in theatres" I used to do theater lighting when I was a young'n, and I actually met an old timer who recalled doing that very thing using soup cans and coffee cans for the electrodes. He did it for a low-budget, amateur theater. _Real_ theaters in his day used great huge banks of air-cooled rheostats.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Before my time. The stage lighting in my (relatively new at the time) HS used good old Variacs.

Answer (score 2):

There's a variety of ways to make a resistor.

A pretty simple way is taking a pencil and rubbing the pointy end on a substrate like paper. A number 2 pencil has graphite that will give you basically 10k ohms give or take 5k ohms of resistance per square centimeter.

You then touch the multimeter probes to either side of the resistor. You can move one end closer to the other for a variable resistor.

This is called a pencil resistor or graphite resistor.